# Creating complex-featurerich yet comprehensive user-intuitive search forms with .net riaservices

Tags: silverlight, search, wcf-ria-services

I need to make some complex, feature rich search forms for my silverlight application, but I need to do it in a way that the user understands, so it's not only me as a developer who thinks that it's really smart. Are there any guidelines or guides that can help me to do this? I think I've created the form and erased it 3 times now, I really want to make it work properly.

Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you got someone from marketing to define your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a lot of reading to do.  I would recommend three books:-

- "The Design the of Everyday Things" by Donald A. Norman
- "The Inmates are Running the Asylum" by Alan Cooper
- "About Face 3" by Alan Cooper

Also check out the [.Toolbox](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/) design course although you will need blend follow that.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look on the following document:

http://www.nngroup.com/reports/flash/RIA-usability.pdf

The document is from 2002 but it is still current.

The following article contains some great info too:

http://www.uxmag.com/design/rich-internet-application-screen-design

The following link contains live UI patterns:

http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Search

It's an app in SL that let's you browse UI patterns.